# document.all[test].innerHTML not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript

I am trying

```
 function ddtip(thetest, thetext)
```

`var Test = document.all[thetest].innerHTML;`

```
var str = document.all[thetext].value;
var MyArray = str.split(",");
```

but it is not working in Firefox but the same is working in IE. **thetest** and **thetext** are the ID of the Server Controls.

I also tried with document.getElementById[thetest].innerHTML; but it is throwing error.

Please Help.

Thanks,

Rahul

Comment: **Post some relevant code please**. We should know what `thetest` is. Anyway `document.all` is a deprecated property(and it was only defined in IE)

Comment: If `thetest` is not a string variable holding an ID of a HTML element then it will fail. If the id is actually `"thetest"` then you are of course missing your speech marks `document.getElementById("thetest");` also IE is more forgiving with IDs. So it may be that you have a name for your element but no ID. This would explain IE working and firefox throwing an error

Comment: Try `document.getElementById(thetest).innerHTML;` you were using square brackets instead of parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "thetest" is a variable then getElementById should work. If it is the id of the element you are looking for then it should be like this: document.getElementById('thetest')

Comment: This should be a comment more than an answer. Moreover, it is wrong and will cause an `undefined` reference, since `document.getElementById` won't have `thetest` property set.